# How to add combobox on datagridviewcell doubleclick

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have application with datagridview which contain 2 columns. By double clicking datagrid text cell convert to combobox and its selected element must be cell value. Once user change selected item, combobox convert to textcolumn (items bounds to combobox by datatable).

Edited:

```
DatagridViewcomboboxColumn col= new DatagridViewcomboboxColumn();
 col.DataSource = datatble; 
col.ValueMember = "Location_Name";
col.DisplayMember = "Location_Name";
col.DataPropertyName = "Location_Name";
datagridview1.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: Why not just use the ComboBox column?

Comment: @ sriram sakthivel - will u please elaborate us suggestion. M tried But I did not get

Comment: @Abhishek- see my edited code.. It just show column to datagriedview but it did not dropdown

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found another simple solution. These are the steps:

1. Add a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn instead of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.
2. Add a ComboBox to the form and hide it.
3. Handle the CellDoubleClick event. In the handler, locate the ComboBox to the position of the current cell, set its value to the text of the current cell and show it.

   ```
   private void Form_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       combobox1.Hide();
       this.datagridview1.Controls.Add(combobox1);
   }

   private void dataGridView2_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
       this.combobox1.Location = this.datagridview1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Location;
      this.combobox1.SelectedValue = this.datagridview1.CurrentCell.Value;
      this.combobox1.Show();
   }
   ```

   See this code.

**EDIT**:

just drag drop datagridview and one dropdown onto form and set some text for dropdown....there you go. here i paste the full working sample form you. let me know face any problem.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cboDepartment.Visible = false;
            InitGrid();
        }

        private void InitGrid()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Department", typeof(string));

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "";
            dr["Department"] = "";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "";
            dr["Department"] = "";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "";
            dr["Department"] = "";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "";
            dr["Department"] = "";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "";
            dr["Department"] = "";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            cboDepartment.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                this.cboDepartment.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Location;
                this.cboDepartment.Size = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Size;
                this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(cboDepartment);
                cboDepartment.Select();
                cboDepartment.Focus();
                cboDepartment.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cboDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged);
                if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() == "")
                    cboDepartment.SelectedIndex = 0;
                else
                    this.cboDepartment.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                this.cboDepartment.Show();

            }
        }

        private void cboDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboDepartment.Text != "--Select--")
            {
                DataGridViewCell dgvc = (DataGridViewCell)dataGridView1[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
                dgvc.Value = cboDepartment.Text;
                cboDepartment.Visible = false;
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboDepartment.Visible)
            {
                if (this.cboDepartment.Location == 
                    this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex, true).Location)
                {
                    this.cboDepartment.Size = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex, true).Size;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: one thing i like to know say that the way u want to place combo box on datagrid cell that way followed in VB6. i have given u that code which fulfil your purpose but this approach people do not like in .Net.

Comment: I already use this solution once but combo size does not fit to datagridview cell. I can increase width but not height. I want to  that  combobox must fit  to datagridview cell. Is ther any solution?

Comment: see this link https://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/combobox-with-datagridview-in-c/ they work with datagridview combobox column.

Comment: see my updated answer. all ready for you. thanks. vote me if my answer help.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to achieve is not an easy task, so i suppose you should use the ComboBox Column, but if you want to spent some time on working out your own solution you should read this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

BUT it is a lot of work, so if you want results iin less then 3-4 hours you should use what Sriram Sakthivel suggested in his comment!